# min/max/saddle $z=x^3+y^3-4xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> find min/max/saddle points $$z=x^3+y^3-4xy$$

$z_x:3x^2-4y$

$z_y:3y^2-4x$

$z_{xx}: 6x$

$z_{yy}: 6y$

$z_{xy}: -4$

$z_x: 3x^2-4y=0\Rightarrow y=\frac{3x^2}{4}$

$z_y: 3(\frac{3x^2}{4})^2 -4x=0\Rightarrow \frac{27}{16}x^4-4x=0\Rightarrow x(\frac{27}{16}x^3-4)=0$

$x_1=0$

$\frac{27}{16}x^3-4=0\Rightarrow x^3=\frac{64}{26}$

$x_2=\frac{4}{3}$

to get the value of $y$ in which equation should I plug the x's? if I use $z_x$ I get one value, in $z_y$ I get to values

Comment: Plug your $x$ values into $y=\frac{3x^2}{4}$, that would be easiest. That will give you the two critical points of $z$.

Comment: @EthanHunt but this give me 1 value for each $x$ point:
$(0,0)$ and $(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$ if I plug it in $3y^2-4x$ I get $y=0,+-\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: Have you tested those two points to determine if they are max/min/saddle points?

Comment: @EthanHunt yes, but before so, In one way I get 2 points and on the other 3 points, how can it be?

Comment: @gbox Because one way you are not using all the information you are given.

Comment: @almagest so in general I need to plug it to the equation that will give more information ?

Comment: The safe thing is to check that is satisfies all the constraints. So having found $(\frac{4}{3},-\frac{4}{3})$ as a possible saddle/min/max point you check that it gives $z_x=z_y=0$.

Comment: @almagest in the case of $-\frac{4}{3}$ ,$z_x=z_y\neq 0$